# How to use DS3231 RTC with Arduino to improve millis() accuracy?

Tags: arduino, milliseconds

I am building a stopwatch that must have a millisecond precision.
The precision of the millis () function of arduino is not sufficient to guarantee a good result.

I read this answer:

[How to get millisecond resolution from DS3231 RTC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44644383/how-to-get-millisecond-resolution-from-ds3231-rtc)

But it does not work because the DS3231 option 2 frequency in not 1KHz but 1Hz. Then the code count the seconds not the milliseconds.

How can I solve?

Thank you

Comment: How long is your stop watch period? I would use the internal clock if you are watching no longer than a couple of minutes. An external quartz is necessary to have a stable clock for a long period of time. For short periods, the internal clock drift is usually neglectable

Comment: From ten seconds to five minutes.

Comment: in this case I suggest to reconsider whether or not the internal clock is sufficient. If not, use the DS3221 RTC in the configuration suggested by my answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you really need millisecond accuracy, I suggest using the [DS3221 RTC](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/DS3231.pdf) in the following configuration

```
RS2 = 0
RS1 = 1
```

This gives you a resolution of 1024 Hz which you can fairly easily convert to milliseconds.